# Laravel 5 checkbox can only 'change' database input once

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a list of projects which can be 'completed' or 'not completed' with a checkbox.

Now when a project is not finished and I use the checkbox to mark it is finished, same way other way around it works.

But then for example: *I have a unfinished project that I want to mark as finished it works, but then I want to mark it as unfinished again and that wont work. It will stay as 'finished' instead of going back to 'unfinished' again.* how can I fix this?

**Controller:**

```
class ProjectController extends Controller
{
private $project;

public function __construct(Project $project){

    $this->project = $project;

    $this->project  = $project
        ->with('user');
}

public function getUsersTotal () {
    $project_users = DB::table('users')
        ->select('browser')
        ->groupBy('browser')
        ->get();
}

public function index()
{
    $projects = Project::get();

    return view('project.index', array('projects' => $projects));
}


public function create()
{
    return view('project.create');
}


public function store(CreateProjectRequest $request, Project $project)
{
    $project->create($request->all());

    return redirect()->route('project.index');
}


public function show($id)
{
    //
}


public function edit($id)
{
    $project = $this->project->find($id);


    return view('project.edit', ['project' => $project, 'id' => 'edit']);
}



public function update(CreateProjectRequest $request, $project)
{
    $project = $this->project->find($project);
    $project->fill($request->input())->save();

    return redirect('project');
}


public function destroy($projectId)
{
    $this->project->destroy($projectId);

    return redirect('project');
}
}
```

**HTML(Blade):**

```
{!! Form::model($project, ["route"=>   ['project.update',$project->id] , "method" => 'PATCH']) !!}

@include('project._form')
        <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('completed') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
           {!! Form::label('name', trans('common.completed'), ['class' => 'form-label']) !!}
           {!! Form::checkbox('completed', '1', false, ['class' => '']) !!}
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="form-group">
           {!! Form::submit( trans('common.edit'), ["class"=>"btn btn-primary"]) !!}
        </div>
 {!! Form::close() !!}

 {!! delete_form(['project.destroy', $project->id]) !!}
```

Comment: Are the changes getting reflected in your database? And also check if you are getting expected input.

Comment: @synyster Are you allowing the value null in the database? as a uncheck checkbox returns null. What i always do with checkboxes is changing their value to 1 or 0 depending on if its checked or not.

Comment: @AbhishekPatel Yes, on default the int = 0, so unfinished. After checking the box it will get int = 1, so finished. If I uncheck again it will stay int = 1, so finished.

Comment: @Szenis no, the int is whether 0 or 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need this just before your checkbox definition:

```
<input name='completed' type='hidden' value='0'>
{!! Form::checkbox('completed', '1', false, ['class' => '']) !!}
```

This will make sure that a value of `0` is sent to the application when the checkbox is not checked.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with the checkbox is that it's value is not in the Request if the checkbox is unchecked. Therefore not saved to the database upon using create() or not changing an existing value with update().

The best answer I found is to create a `Form Request` validator (as shown in [this laracast on form validation](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/12) and in the `rules()` function check for existence of the checkmark, if not, append it. The advantage is that it works in all situations (create new and update) and that it's code that sits in one place without adding hidden fields in your form or setters in your Model. Just a clean solution.

This post shows how it's done: http://novate.co.uk/laravel-5-checkbox-processing/

Example:

```
$this->merge(['attribute_name' => $this->input('attribute_name', false)]);
```